# Dirichlet's approximation theorem

Tags: diophantine-approximation

A corollary of Dirichlet's approximation theorem is that for any irrational $\alpha$, there are infinitely many integer solutions of $$\left|\frac{p}{q}-\alpha\right|<\frac{1}{q^2}$$ 
Are there any similar results concerning the integer solutions of $$0<\frac{p}{q}-\alpha<\frac{1}{q^2}?$$

Comment: [Kronecker's approximation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html) allows to approximate $0$ with $\{m\alpha +n \mid m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ (which is effectively dense) from any side of $\alpha$, although not as tight as $\frac{1}{m}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approximations that come from the convergents to the continued fraction for $\alpha$ all satisfy the Dirichlet inequality and alternate between being bigger than and being smaller than $\alpha$.

Comment: Oh yes, completely forgot about that (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For every irrational $\alpha$ there are infinitely many integer solutions of
$$0<\frac pq-\alpha<\frac1{q^2}. $$
(And by symmetry also infinitely many solutions of $0<\alpha-\frac pq<\frac1{q^2}$).

---

For irrational $\alpha\in(0,1)$, we can start with approximations
$$ \frac 01<\alpha<\frac11$$
and step-wise improve by splitting at the Farey-sum, i.e. from
$$\tag1 \frac ab<\alpha<\frac cd$$
we go to 
$$\tag2 \frac ab<\alpha<\frac {a+c}{b+d}\qquad\text{or}\qquad\frac {a+c}{b+d}<\alpha<\frac cd.$$
The difference between upper and lower bound in $(1)$ is $\frac1{bd}$, hence we have $0<\frac cd-\alpha<\frac1{d^2}$ at least whenever $b>d$.
Hence the only way to *not* have infinitely many such approximations is to almost always choose the left interval in $(2)$. But that is impossible for irrational $\alpha$ because sooner or later the interval length becomes less than $\alpha-\frac ab$.